# YouTube Traffic Sources by Video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've set up a project in google and have been able to get Daily Video Views by traffic source, aggregated to the channel level. Have used the following request (with OAuth 2.0 token).

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel==[ChannelID]&start-date=[STARTDATE]&end-date=[ENDDATE]&metrics=views,estimatedMinutesWatched&dimensions=day,insightTrafficSourceType&filters=country==US&include-historical-channel-data=true&max-results=1000

Ideally, I'd be able to add "Video" to the dimensions list, but adding video granularity with insightTrafficSourceType does not seem possible. As such, I feel as though I need to get a list of all videos that have been played between [STARTDATE] and [ENDDATE], and make a request for each video.

Is this correct, and do you know of the best way to get a list of all videos played on [ChannelID] between the two dates? Is this possible?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) for your purpose. Set the part parameter to '`snippet`' then provide values for '`channelID`', `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore`. You can filter more by providing parameters in the '`q`' field.

Paste this on your URL for demo purposes. Provide values for `channelID` and `API_KEY` (from Google Dev Console). It will fetch videos from your channel between year 2017 and year 2018.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=API_KEY&publishedAfter=2017-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&publishedBefore=2018-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&channelId=YOUR_CHANNEL_ID&maxResults=25
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure this would work exactly. Let's assume a video was posted on December 31st 2015. If we wanted video views for all of 2016, getting the list of videos posted in 2016 and following that views by video for 2016, we would not have requested data for that video which was posted in December 2015. Do you know if there a way of getting daily play count by video, and then passing those video IDs into the traffic source request, instead of daily videos released? Thanks again!